# RabbitMQ несколько очередей на одного потребителя

Tags: java, rabbitmq

В мою систему отправляется больше количество сообщений из разных систем. Допустим, сообщения для автомобилей разных марок.

При каждой отправке новой марки автомобилей из какой-либо системы создается новая очередь (например, `auto.kia`, `auto.lada` и т.п.) в итоге в реббите может быть произвольное количество очередей.

Но, у меня есть один воркер (*Consumer*), который должен собирать и обрабатывать сообщения из всех этих очередей. Как реализовать множества очередей одним воркером?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Звучит как классический случай [topic exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html).

В них требуется, чтобы `routing_key` в сообщениях **отправителя** (producer) состоял из набора слов, разделённых точками, ваши `auto.lada` и `auto.kia` как раз подходят.

Тогда `binding_key` **принимающего** (consumer), содержащий спецсимволы `*` и `#` играет роль **шаблона** вроде регулярного выражения:

- `*` означает "одно любое слово"
- `#` означает "любое число (даже 0) любых слов".

...и ключи `auto.lada` и `auto.kia` оба подойдут под шаблон `auto.*` у принимающего.

Переменной при таком раскладе будет **не очередь**, а **ключ сообщений** (routing key для отправителя). Распределение происходит в рамках **одной очереди**. Много очередей для этой цели вам и не нужно. Подробнее в [руководстве по AMQP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html).

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @regen если вам помог ответ, пометьте его как правильный

Comment: вроде работает, но мне необходимо, чтобы в веб интерфейсе реббита я мог видеть названия очередей и сколько на данный момент в каждой  находится сообщений.

Comment: @regen веб-интерфейсом кролика такое, насколько я знаю, не провернуть. А получить принимающим список доступных очередей AMQP тоже не умеет. Разве что следить за количествами отдельно. Как -- не знаю, не интересовался.

Comment: хорошо, а как такой вариант: все сообщения приходят в одну очередь auto. и я создаю несколько воркеров, которые эту очередь разбирают. единственная проблема, в эту очередь будут отправляться сотни тысяч или даже миллионы сообщений в день, скажется ли как-то на производительности, если я буду использовать только одну очередь?

Comment: @regen вряд ли сильно, центральный узел же всё равно один (хотя средствами эрланга распределить их можно, нужны навыки). Но лучше всего измерьте.